# Splitting the normalized database table for fast access?

Tags: sql, database, database-indexes

I have a normalized table in the database-- say

```
(ID, name, age)
```

Here, every entry corresponds to a person, and ID is the key of this table.

There is frequent access by the non-key fields-- this table is searched by the name field often enough for one thing.

So for that, I can put an index on the name field and thus, the table is indexed also on this field.

The CTO says that this table is to be broken into N tables-- one for each of the 
non-key fields (N=2 in this case):

```
(ID, name)
(ID, age)
```

He suggests this for fast access for the queries. When broken down like this, each of these two tables 
have the ID as the key still, and the tables are not indexed on the other field.

To my opinion, this doesn't provide fast access-- even slows it down:

- no index means searching the entire table again on a query
- an additional table access to bring the entire row of the original table (name & age)
  rather than fetching them both on the corresponding row(s) when the matching row(s) are found.

What's missing here?

TIA

Comment: You're correct. The proposed solution does not provide any benefit.

Comment: thx - if you write this as an answer i'll accept. I believe it's a full ans-- looked for verification.

Comment: Please indicate what database you are referring to. Perhaps it's some type of proprietary DB and perhaps he knows something about it, you and I don't. I've worked with a proprietary DB before, which would read entire rows, before filtering. If you are talking about a normal, modern RDBMS then I would suggest your CTO is a clown.

Comment: @Michael.M - the good old MySQL with Hibernate, nothing else there. wasn't sure whether I'm missing something myself-- that odd.

Comment: *"When broken down like this, each of these two tables have the ID as the key still, and the tables are not indexed on the other field."* What's the logic behind *not* indexing the non-key columns?

Comment: How does that guy get to be the CTO ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is absolutely correct and the proposed solution does not provide any benefits and even makes matters worse exactly in the ways you describe.

Adding indexes to the fields that are frequently searched would yield better results, but depending on the search method, the realized benefits might be limited. For example, searching for partial matches  (`name LIKE '%whatever%'`) might not make effective use of the indexes.

Depending on the database you're using, there might me other techniques available to speed things up, e.g. memory caching, full-text indexing etc.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it degrades performance over-all and is bad design. On top of that you should maintain foreign key constraints so that it would not be possible to delete, if needed .. (ID, name) without also deleting (ID, age). These FK constraints will add their own overhead. Alternatively you might opt to not implement the FK but then you open up the dataset to the possibility of unmatched records. This scenario is possible with common ORM tools that will not write functions for you. On the other hand, with functions you can use transactions and ensure that both pass or fail together. This is even true for writes. What if, for example Mary Smith gets married and her name changes to Mary White. On top of that we need to change her age. Now with the proposed design it would be prudent to make sure that both tables are updated in one DB transaction which adds more complexity

Then there is the issue of MySQL maintenance. Adding more tables than needed to the design will also hamper maintenance efforts and add more load to MySQL's own index maintenance overhead.

So besides degrading DB performance it also degrades developer productivity because of the added useless complexity.

If performance is really such an issue, and your dataset really that large, and you have really need fast text look-ups etc, then the better and widely used technique would be to use something like Sphinx.

Honestly, it sounds like he may have read something about sharding, and completely misunderstood what he was reading.